# Recoding binomial variables in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, recode

I need to clean/modify the data, but I am interested in data where var1=0 only. Can I 'permanently' remove the data where var1=0 or is missing, so that I can simplify my codes.
For example,for summary statistics i have 
mytable <- xtabs(~var1+ var2+var3, data = mydata), but i would like to cross tab with only two variables (var2 and var3)where var1=0.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something:

```r
mydata_clean <- mydata[mydata$var1 !=0,] # to remove rows data where var1 = 0

mytable <- xtabs(~var2+var3, data = mydata_clean) # to perform xtabs on var2 and var3 only
```

If it does not work, you should put a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data, it will make things easier for people trying to help you.

Comment: @Beata, glad to hear ;)